# Check if line lies between two planes

Tags: geometry

I have a line given by an equation $$\vec{p} = \vec{l}_0 + d\vec{l}$$ where $\vec{l}$ is a direction vector of a line, $l_0$ is a point on a line and $d$  is some scalar. I know that this line is parallel to two planes, both given by a point lying on a plane and a normal. I want to distinguish if the line lies between those two planes.

Comment: In 3D, what does it mean for something to be between two planes, in general? Are the normals of the two planes parallel?

Comment: Why only two planes?

Comment: @MattiP. those two planes are parallel.

Comment: @dmtri I want to ckeck if line is lying between two planes when two planes are parallel and this line is also parallel to those planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider the projections on a line perpendicular to the planes.

Let $\vec a$, $\vec b$ be the points on the planes, and $\vec n$ the common normal vector of the planes (I'm assuming the planes are parallel, otherwise the question is meaningless). The line lies between the planes if
$$
\vec a\cdot\vec n < \vec l_0\cdot\vec n < \vec b\cdot\vec n
$$
or the analogous reversed inequality.